# Using the value of a variable assigned inside an If Statement within Input Step of Scripted Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a sample scripted pipeline like so:

```
def a = 9
def b = 6
def c = 7
def d = 5

def userInputs(){
  timeout(time:10, unit:'MINUTES'){
  chosenInputs = input(
  id:'Proceed', message: 'choose', parameters:[
    [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue:"${name}", description:'Your name', name:'username'],
    [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue:"${age}", description:'No of Pods', name:'userAge']])
  }
}

node{
  userInputs()
if (a > b){
  name= "Peace"
  age="4"
}
  name = "{chosenInputs['username']}"
  age = "{chosenInputs['userAge']}"
  println ("User Input:\n" + chosenInputs)
  
timeout(time:10, unit:'MINUTES')  {   
if (d < c){
        name=${name}
        age=${age}
        println("Name: ${name}")
        println("Age: ${age}")
        
      }
}
      //println("Name: $name")
      //println("Age: $age")
}
```

My goal is to set the default value of my parameters in the input step to the values of the variables (name and age) in my if statement when the condition is true. However, I am getting the error `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: name for class: groovy.lang.Binding at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)` . I have also tried to declare name and age as global vars but that did not work either.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You have a few issues.  Firstly, your method is called before you declare or initialize your variables.  Secondly, you only declare and initialize the variables when the conditional evaluates true. Try the following

```
def a = 9
def b = 6
def c = 7
def d = 5

def userInputs() {
  timeout(time:10, unit:'MINUTES') {
     chosenInputs = input(id:'Proceed', message: 'choose', parameters:[
       [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue:"${name}", description:'Your name', name:'username'],
       [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue:"${age}", description:'No of Pods', name:'userAge']])
   }
}

node {

   if (a > b){
      name= "Peace"
      age="4"
   } else {
      name = ""
      age = ""
   }

  userInputs()
  
  // other code

}
```